# Google Drive video embed get 404 randomly

Tags: google-drive-api, video-streaming, embed

I get this url to view a google drive video from google api v3: `https://docs.google.com/file/d/1fpCiX2ujTMkvo8mQa3CTKUXTWxrtaIxc/preview`

The problem is that after I press the play button on the poster image the video randomly fails with a 404 error. I have found the request that fails `https://docs.google.com/u/0/get_video_info?docid=1fpCiX2ujTMkvo8mQa3CTKUXTWxrtaIxc` and copy on postman,you can see the failure here:

[image: you can see how it fails here][link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejbh4.gif)

Comment: What do you mean by `after I press the play button on the poster image the video randomly fails`? I get a 404 error in the console but the video loads without issue in my environment.

Comment: is a random error. I cant understand the problem here. I post the query that fails, but sometimes works fine.

Comment: Can you also post the full error on the left? The one that contains `se pudo obtener... previa del archivo... Hubo un problema...` etc? Also, how often are you making the call to get the video, and how often does it seem to fail?